# Why does this Webcam code not work?

Tags: c#, .net, webcam

**Situation**

A while ago, I found code snippets for webcam capturing and minimized it for what I really need - capturing images, that's all. No device selection, no async timers, I just needed to capture images.

Below is the code. It doesn't have any checks and I know it is not exactly how good code looks like, but I wouldn't post huge code snippets here anyway.

It used to work well, however, recently I tried to run it again and it didn't work although my webcam does indeed work fine with any other program.

```
public static class Webcam
{
    private static IntPtr Handle;

    public static void Start()
    {
        Handle = capCreateCaptureWindowA("WebCap", 0, 0, 0, 320, 240, 0, 0);
        SendMessage(Handle, 1034, 0, 0);
        SendMessage(Handle, 1074, 0, 0);
    }
    public static void Stop()
    {
        SendMessage(Handle, 1035, 0, 0);
    }
    public static Image CaptureFrame()
    {
        SendMessage(Handle, 1084, 0, 0);
        SendMessage(Handle, 1054, 0, 0);      // <--- returns 0
        return (Image)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImport("avicap32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr capCreateCaptureWindowA(string lpszWindowName, int dwStyle, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, int hwndParent, int nID);
}
```

**Environment**

Operating System: Windows 8 x64
Used webcam: Logitech C910 *(Drivers are properly installed)*

**Question:** What is wrong with this code and why does it not work?

Comment: did you change anything related to drivers or OS since the last time you (successfully) tried to run this code? also, what do you mean by "It doesn't work"? error message / no image / ...?

Comment: "It doesn't work" means that `CaptureFrame()` returns `null`. Since it has been 1-2 years or so I can't really tell what has changed. But the webcam still works fine.